# Find the table name with the data value

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SQL Server 2008 R2. Now I want to write a SQL statement to find the table name that an column of that table contains the word 'happy'. The column name `like '%abc'` may contains the word

Can anyone give me some ideas?

Thanks,
V

Comment: Do you want to get all tables which have a column that contains the word 'happy'?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
select obj.name 
    from sys.columns col join sys.tables obj
    on col.name like '%happy%'
      and col.object_id = obj.object_id
```